# Function works for NON dynamically loaded images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/m2barfho/

Hi I have the following function:

```
  var imgs = $('img');
  if ($(imgs).hasClass('cboxPhoto')) {
    imgs.each(function() {
      var img = $(this);
      if ($(img).width() > 1000 && $(img).height() > 1000) {
        img.addClass('relative');
      } 
      else {
        img.removeClass('relative');
      }
    });
  }
```

I am essentially stating if an `<img>` has the class of "cboxPhoto" then run the each() function to add the class of "relative" if the image width is greater than x it's height is greater than x. This function works fine when the HTML is already statically placed in. However, these images are dynamically generated, I've tried

```
$('#body').load('index.html #cboxLoadedContent', function() {
}
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {} with .`load`
```

also tried adding an `.on` event listener, even though I was not using binding events to see if when it is loaded it might detect.

THE PROBLEM:
The images are dynamically generated via an upload module, and not statically placed in. Colorbox for some reason will not run my function. The images have the class `.cboxPhoto`. How can I have my hasClass function detect a dynamically generated image, and run the preceding each() function? It works in my fiddle, but not my index?

Comment: Your fiddle link is wrong

Comment: `$(imgs).hasClass('cboxPhoto')` will only check that the first img in the collection has that class, also you do not need to wrap `imgs` since its already a jQuery object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the images based on if they have the `cboxPhoto` class, then loop through them.

```
var imgs = $('img.cboxPhoto');
imgs.each(function() {
  var img = $(this);
  if (img.width() > 1000 && img.height() > 1000) {
    img.addClass('relative');
  } else {
    img.removeClass('relative');
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2barfho/5/)

Comment: Accepting this for the checking of every <image>.

Comment: No need to loop through every image, just use the class selector, `imgs = $('img.cboxPhoto')`, that way the only images in the collection will be the ones with that class